# "I am going to have to", "I have to", and "I will have to"

Tags: differences, future, auxiliary-verbs, will-be-going

What is the difference between these two:

- I am going to have to see you sometime.
- I have to see you sometime.

When would you use the first one?

On that note, how is . . .

- I will have to see you sometime.

. . . any different from the two sentences previously mentioned?

Answer (score 5):

"I have to see you sometime" means any time in the future, starting now. "No time like now" is a valid reply to that, suggesting the "sometime" to be very, very soon.

“I am going to have to see you sometime” puts an additional time delay during which you won't have to see that person - such time will come eventually, but the nearest future is exempt.

As for will/going to, I suggest [previous answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19378/what-are-the-guidelines-for-usage-of-will-and-is-are-going-to) distinguishing the two.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked about the difference between the first two of the following; when one would you use the first form; and how the first two differ from the last.

> • I am going to have to see you sometime.
>   • I have to see you sometime.
>   • I will have to see you sometime.

The general meaning of all three is the same: I must see you, at some future time.  To my thinking, there is no indication built into any of these as to how soon I must see you.  Depending on context and tone, in any of these three, *sometime* might be made to mean right away, or at an indefinite time, or any time, or never. Likewise, tone can make each verb show reluctance, resignation, eagerness.  Also, in any of the three, meaning depends on where emphasis is placed.  Half a dozen nuances arise for each, as emphasis is placed on the subject, the verb, the auxiliary, the infinitive, the object, the adverb, or on combinations of same.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to see you sometime,
be going to do something used to show what somebody intends to do in the future.
thus, I intend to see you sometime in the future, it's not an imperative sentence.

I have to see you sometime,
have to used to show that you must do something.
thus, I must see you sometime, it's an imperative sentence.

I will have to see you sometime.
I must see you in the future, it's an imperative sentence.